# Can I extract my import statements to different files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, enzyme

I was writing tests for my React components, and I realized that I was writing the same code over and over again for the test setups (i.e., import statements, Enzyme configs, etc.)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import SomeComponent from './index';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('SomeComponent', () => {
// test block...
```

Is there a way to extract this common setup code to a different location? For instance, I would like to create a file named something like 'testConfig.js' that includes the above lines, and just import that file for all my test files.

Answer (score 0):

To configure enzyme I usually use a setupTests.js file in my src dir

```
import { configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

configure({
   adapter: new Adapter()
});
```

so I don't have to configure enzyme in every tests file. It works for jest i don't know about other test libs